# How to extract the result form array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to extract the result from below array

```
 Array ( [model_type] =>
        Array ( [label] => Model Type
                [value] => Inspiron 
                [code] => model_type )
         [model_version] => 
        Array ( [label] => Model Version
                [value] => 100L
                [code] => model_version )
        [color] => 
         Array ( [label] => Color 
                 [value] => Black
                 [code] => color )
    )
```

How can i get the result Model type as Inspiron and color as black

Please help , Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this the array content, or does the array actually exist in a variable?

Comment: @Daedalus i have pinted the array it is actually a variable

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this content, this is a rather simple answer.  Simply type `$yourvariable['model_type']['value'];` and `$yourvariable['color']['value'];`.  This will get you both of the vailes you are after, assuming your variable is called `$yourvariable`.  I would suggest you give [the manual](https://www.php.net/) a read when you get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
foreach($results  as $key => $value)
{ 
   if($key == 'model_type') 
      echo $value['value'];

    if($key == 'model_version')
     echo $value['color'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do the following :

```
$model = $result['model_type']['value'];

$color = $result['color']['value'];
```

and then simply echo both values

```
echo $model . " is " . $color;
```